# Extract portion of a file name in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, extract

I am a newbie to Linux and am trying to extract portion of a filename from the absolute path in a bash script. For example, if the path is /opt/data/filename-attribute.dat, I am able to get the path of the directory and the file as follows:

```
sourcedir=`dirname $path`
name=`basename $path`
```

I would like to extract attribute from the file and was wondering if there was a quick way in shell script to perform this. I can get filename-attribute by

```
f=${name%%[.]*}
```

and would like to extract just the attribute.

Comment: If the suffix is always exactly `.dat` you could use `basename $path .dat` etc...

Comment: You are asking about filename extensions.  Attributes are a very different thing.  See attr(5)  (eg, execute "man 5 attr")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is just to do it in two steps:

```
f="${name%.*}"   # strip everything from the last dot onward
f="${f##*-}"     # strip everything up through the last hyphen
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right

```
a="${f#*-}"
```